# Barcode reader converts numeric english text to arabic

Tags: ms-access, barcode

I have a barcode reader that reads a barcode from a student card into unbound access form field. The barcode is a text of english numbers. The problem is sometimes the barcode reader reads just OK with no problems, but, the othertimes it reads the text in arabic numbers as in the example below:

```
5874859  read as: ٥٨٧٤٨٥٩
```

is there any setting I have to do with barcode reader to read the text as english numbers always ? or should I handle this problem using vba ?

Comment: Maybe need different barcode font installed. If there is some setting that needs to be changed, most likely it is in the barcode reader device driver. Consult the device documentation and/or manufacturer. No idea how VBA could handle this. Your question is too broad, lacks code and debugging so not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Check `numeral shapes` and `keyboard language` settings of textbox.

Comment: I found Numeral Shapes but not Keyboard Language. If this is intermittent issue with one textbox, don't see how property setting could be cause. But if this behavior is consistent with different textboxes, then could be property setting.

Answer (score 0):

For those who having same problem, I fixed it by setting the keyboard layout properity of the text field to 'international'.